# 500 Internal Server Error after file transfer

Tags: magento-1.6, file-upload

I have had some trouble setting up a magento store, some files seemed to be missing or had gone broken in my previous file transfer, so I decided to do another file transfer in binary mode using FileZilla, because I read that using ASCII could modify the files.

Upon completing the entire file transfer, I am getting an 500 Internal Server Error

See below for exact error message (with the exception of the *contact your web host* bit):

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

I've tried changing file permissions and on specific folders as suggested by some, without success. I have the `magento-check.php`  and `magento-cleanup.php` utilities on my root directory, but I can't seem to access them through `www.yourdomain.com/magento/magento-cleanup.php` etc..

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: Just for S&G have you tried http://yourdomain.com/ without the `www` prefix?

Comment: Hello Tim, thanks for your response, it was actually after your feedback on my previous thread a week or so ago, that I decided to give this form of transfer a go (not exactly what you adviced - but it should be safer for large file transfers) I've tried both with and without now, but unfortunately, neither worked!

Answer (score 1):

If you're transferring from a Windows computer, binary transfer preserved CRLF (\r\n) line endings and Linux expects LF (\n) line endings and is complaining mightily because probably a file like every .htaccess file or a shell script is unreadable due to this.

PHP is line-ending agnostic, the shell and Apache might not be. Check your server's **http error log** to see what's generating the 500 error.

After determining which files are causing the problem, upload each one using text transfer. Magento uses quite a few `.htaccess` files to ensure security by rendering whole directories unreadable externally or by denying execution of php files out of the media folders (remote exploit).

Comment: Hello Fiasco, thanks for your feedback, i'll do a clean file transfer in a different mode then, I looked in an error file, and from what I can tell there's a lot of things going bad..